# PowerShell Return the total number of emails from a PST file

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to count all of the items from a PST file which is located in C:\PST folder.

I've came up with this but is not working correctly:

```
(Get-ChildItem c:\pst -filter "*.pst" | measure).Count
```

I have 10 emails in the PST and after running this code I just get 1 as a result instead of 10.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: That is finding the *1* file. You would have to have something open the PST file to access its contents. Usually this would be done through Outlook in my experience.

Comment: Unfortunately it is more complicated then that. Get-ChildItem returns files and not their contents. PST files have a proprietary file structure which is read by something like outlook or other third party utility. If you have outlook you could use that to get the information you need. An example is [here](http://poshcode.org/2695)

Comment: Thanks @Matt. The PST which I am trying to read its content is corrupt so I cannot load it in Outlook. I have an application which extract all the content/emails from PST even if its corrupted. I was just looking for a way to use PowerShell and check how many emails are in the PST and compare with what my application extracted. As you mentioned, this is more complex than i've thought.

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician. As I already mentioned to Matt, I am looking for a way to avoid using Outlook.

Comment: If you don't want to use Outlook you can use [Dmitry's Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) to gain access to a PST parser, but one way or another you have to have something that can try to parse the PST file. If you want to use Redemption take a look at RDO, and the documentation for it.